# Message not getting to service

Tags: .net, wcf, msmq

I have a WCF service using netMsmqBinding and a client consuming it. I send a message to the service using the client and it gets to the message queue but the service is never activated. I've tried setting break points, exceptions in the constructor, setting the wildcard on the action and a few other things but the service never does anything. The message sits in the message queue.

The message goes into the queue even if I disable IIS.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you running the WCF service in IIS, or is it a stand-alone Windows Service hosting it?

Comment: IIS. as I said, even when I disable IIS the message still gets into the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your service hosted in an application or under a root site node? If not in an application then create one, move the service and use these commands in command prompt (admin mode)

```
appcmd set site "servicesite" -+bindings.[protocol='net.msmq',bindingInformation='localhost']
appcmd set app "servicesite/svcapp" /enabledProtocols:net.msmq
```

where servicesite and svcapp are the names of your IIS site node and application node respectively.

Access your service via web browser and see what you get.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe an MSMQ binding will automatically work in a WCF service hosted in IIS.  I believe you have to use Windows Activation Service (WAS) within IIS, or some other mechanism to get it to work.  This article might give you some info to start with:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-1.aspx

Comment: I've already read all 3 of those articles following the examples. Those articles are using IIS, not a self hosted service. "The last step is to configure IIS 7 to use WAS to listen to the message queue and activate your service when new messages arrive"

Comment: If you've already tried some things, you might want to update your question to indicate what you've tried and why.  These types of things are highly dependent on details, so if you just provide a little info, you can't expect a detailed walkthrough.